# How can I show some text at the end of a query or an arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have this formula that returns all of the avalable records in range D11:D100
At the end of the formula I need to display a message in the second available line indicating that the report has ended.

I have achieved something with an if statement, but it's not ideal as the message will display as many times as there are no records up to 100 times.

={"LIST";ARRAYFORMULA(if(D11:D100="";"END OF REPORT";(D11:D100;")))}

This is what I'm getting

[image: This is what I'm getting]

It would be perfect if I could not only show the message in the second blank line once but also be able to ad another message after the first.

This is what I would like to get

[image: This is the goal]

Comment: whats your query formula?

Comment: Hi Player0, It's just an arrayformula `={"LIST";ARRAYFORMULA(if(D11:D100="";"END OF REPORT";(D11:D100;")))}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your query outputs 1 column:

```
={QUERY(A1:A100, "", 0); "END OF REPORT"}
```

if your query outputs 2 columns:

```
={QUERY(A1:B100, "", 0); {"END OF REPORT", ""}}
```

if your query outputs 3 columns:

```
={QUERY(A1:C100, "", 0); {"END OF REPORT", "", ""}}
```

etc.

---

### update:

use:

```
={"LIST"; FILTER(D11:D100, D11:D100<>""); "END OF REPORT"}
```